# Creating PDF files with Puppeteer generates files too large

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer

We used to generate PDF files with `phantom` and now switching to `puppeteer`.
The files we would generate (~50 files) would come out 40-50 KB in size.

Now that we use `puppeteer` the same files (using the same data, same image for the logo, etc) are generated and range 190-2125 KB in size.

We've tried looking through the npm docs for the package description, or some setting that we can change, but found nothing.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: It is not strictly a puppeteer problem, as much as it is a Chrome problem. Puppeteer uses the same engine as Chrome to print, so you can always test with the Chrome browser and get the same results.
I am facing a similar issue, where around 15mb of photos in a pdf results in a PDF with the size 72mb. Using Firefox i ended up with a 420mb PDF..

Answer (score 2):

As `Puppeteer` uses chromium to generate `pdf` files and according to this  [article](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414976) this is a **known problem**. (scroll to the end.. issue still open) .

You coudl try to "optimize" your `jpeg` files using [imagemin-jpegoptim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-jpegoptim) module or to completetly use some other file type.

What about creating a screenshot as image instead of pdf?

Answer (score 2):

Try the headless mode of puppeteer.

**Note: Use the old headless mode. There is some issue with the new headless mode for whatsoever reason.**

For puppeteer version: >= 22.0.0

```
await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: "shell",
  ...
})
```

For puppeteer version: < 22.0.0

```
await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  ...
})
```

Comment: This worked for me. Dramatically smaller file and faster PDF generation.